# CSS: display:table; and width:100%; not working with images within cell on Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, html-table

I have a design that requires a responsive width, and I have some images that line up next to each other than need vertical alignment so I did the whole `display:table;`, `display:table-cell;` thing.

Unfortunately in Firefox, the images don't scale when the browser is scaled.

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/35Js5/

HTML:

```
<main>
    <article class="companylist relative SectionStyle1">
        <section class="col col4">
            <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/99/MarioSMBW.png" alt="Mario" />
        </section>
        <section class="col col4">
            <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f1/LuigiNSMBW.png" alt="Luigi" />
        </section>
        <section class="col col4">
            <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f5/Toad_3D_Land.jpg" alt="Toad" />
        </section>
        <section class="col col4">
            <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/d/d5/Peach_%28Super_Mario_3D_World%29.png/200px-Peach_%28Super_Mario_3D_World%29.png" alt="Peach" />
        </section>
    </article>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjord+One|Imprima|Reenie+Beanie);
body {
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 62.5%;
    font-family:"Imprima", "Helvetica Neue", "Lucida Grande", "Segoe UI", Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #000;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0;
}
p, ul, ol {
    margin: 1em 0;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    font-size:1.2em
}
li {
    list-style-position:inside;
}
.col { 
    box-sizing:border-box;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    padding:10px 10px; 
}
.col1 {
    width:100%;
}
.col2 {
    width:50%;  
}
.col4 {
    width:25%;    
}
.col8 {
    width:12.5%;   
}
header, footer, main > article {
    padding: 10px 10%;
    width:80%;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
}
.SectionStyle1 {
    background-color:WhiteSmoke;
    color:Black;
}
.companylist {
    display:table;
}
.companylist .col {
    display:table-cell;
    height:200px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    float:none;
}
.companylist .col img {
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%;
}
```

If you pull the fiddle up in Chrome, you can see the behaviour I want and expect in Firefox too.

If I put the `float:left;` on, the cells do shrink, but the vertical alignment is lost :(

I also tried adding a `display:table-row;` element to no avail.

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does adding `table-layout:fixed` to .company-list get what you want? See http://jsfiddle.net/35Js5/5/

Comment: ahh, good one! 
completely forgot about table-layout property.

Answer (score 0):

Try Addidng moz specific styling using :

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
// Your styling
}
```

Here is the fix for your code

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/35Js5/6/

Only addition to your CSS is:

```
 @-moz-document url-prefix() {
.col.col4 img {
max-height:100%;
max-width:100%;
}

.companylist .col {
    width:12.5%; 
    float:left !important;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline;
   }    
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: They don't vertically align in the middle I'm afraid :(